# R/Shiny app: how to make full use of the window?

Tags: r, shiny

In my R/Shiny app, I will have a sidebarPanel and a grid of four wellPanels in the mainPanel. How can I force the app to make use of the full browser window? The width of the wellPanels in each row totals 12, which is the maximum screen width in the Shiny layout grid. What am I missing?

Here's a small example:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  
  # Application title
  titlePanel(
    span(
      span("Stackoverflow example app"),
      span(tags$h4(actionLink("contact", "Contact us")),
           style = "position:absolute;right:2em;")
    ),
    windowTitle = "Stackoverflow example app"
  ),
  
  # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      width = 2,
      sliderInput("bins",
                  "Number of bins:",
                  min = 1,
                  max = 50,
                  value = 30)
    ),
    
    # Show a plot of the generated distribution
    mainPanel(
      # Show a plot of the generated distribution
      mainPanel(
        tagList(
          fluidRow(
            column(6, 
                   offset = 0,
                   wellPanel(
                     plotOutput("distPlot")
                     
                   )
            ),
            column(6, 
                   offset = 0,
                   wellPanel(
                     "Panel 2"
                   )
            )
          ),
          fluidRow(
            column(6, 
                   offset = 0,
                   wellPanel(
                     "Panel 3"
                   )
            ),
            column(6, 
                   offset = 0,
                   wellPanel(
                     "Panel 4"
                     
                   )
            )
          )
        )
      )
    )
  )
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
    # generate bins based on input$bins from ui.R
    x    <- faithful[, 2]
    bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$bins + 1)
    
    # draw the histogram with the specified number of bins
    hist(x, breaks = bins, col = 'darkgray', border = 'white',
         xlab = 'Waiting time to next eruption (in mins)',
         main = 'Histogram of waiting times')
  })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

And a screenshot:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure the sidebar panel and main panel width add up to 12 too. And remove the nested `mainPanel(mainPanel())` you have.

```r
ui <- fluidPage(
  
  # Application title
  titlePanel(
    span(
      span("Stackoverflow example app"),
      span(tags$h4(actionLink("contact", "Contact us")),
           style = "position:absolute;right:2em;")
    ),
    windowTitle = "Stackoverflow example app"
  ),
  
  # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      width = 2,
      sliderInput("bins", "Number of bins:", min = 1, max = 50, value = 30)
    ),
      
    mainPanel(
      width = 10,
      fluidRow(
        column(width = 6, offset = 0, wellPanel(plotOutput("distPlot"))),
        column(width = 6, offset = 0, wellPanel("Panel 2"))
      ),
      fluidRow(
        column(6, offset = 0, wellPanel("Panel 3")),
        column(6, offset = 0, wellPanel("Panel 4"))
      )
    )
  )
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
    # generate bins based on input$bins from ui.R
    x    <- faithful[, 2]
    bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$bins + 1)
    
    # draw the histogram with the specified number of bins
    hist(x, breaks = bins, col = 'darkgray', border = 'white',
         xlab = 'Waiting time to next eruption (in mins)',
         main = 'Histogram of waiting times')
  })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]